# Restlet - Post Object (even with Jaxb) doesnt work

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, restlet, xstream

I tried both: post a object as object or wrapped into JAXBElement. Nothing works for me.

```
//Create Object
Estate DTO estateOne = new EstateDTO("Hotel", "StreetOne", 1, 111111, "England", 1);

    ///setting up xstream
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.processAnnotations(EstateResourceIF.class);
    xstream.processAnnotations(EstateDTO.class);
    xstream.autodetectAnnotations(true);

    xstream.setClassLoader(new EstateDTO().getClass().getClassLoader());
    xstream.alias("estateDTO", EstateDTO.class);
    xstream.alias("estateId", Integer.class);
            xstream.alias("estateName", String.class);

    //post object
    service.post(estateOne).write(System.out);
```

I even tried wrapping it up in JAXB:

```
 JAXBElement<EstateDTO> estate = new JAXBElement<EstateDTO>(new QName("estate"), EstateDTO.class, estateOne);
```

Same issues:
I get:

```
                    Problem creating Marshaller

        javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "com.bachelor.facade.object" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:197)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:128)
            at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:277)
            at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:372)
            at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:337)
            at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.JaxbRepresentation.getContext(JaxbRepresentation.java:97)
            at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.internal.Marshaller$1.initialValue(Marshaller.java:68)
            at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.internal.Marshaller$1.initialValue(Marshaller.java:64)
            at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:141)
            at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:131)
            at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.internal.Marshaller.getMarshaller(Marshaller.java:163)
            at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.internal.Marshaller.marshal(Marshaller.java:216)
            at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.JaxbRepresentation.write(JaxbRepresentation.java:530)
            at org.restlet.engine.io.BioUtils$1.run(BioUtils.java:305)
            at org.restlet.service.TaskService$1$1.run(TaskService.java:132)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
        Unable to locate marshaller.
        JAXB marshalling error caught.

        javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Unable to locate marshaller.
            at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.internal.Marshaller.getMarshaller(Marshaller.java:166)
            at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.internal.Marshaller.marshal(Marshaller.java:216)
            at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.JaxbRepresentation.write(JaxbRepresentation.java:530)
            at org.restlet.engine.io.BioUtils$1.run(BioUtils.java:305)
            at org.restlet.service.TaskService$1$1.run(TaskService.java:132)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
        Problem creating Marshaller

        javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "failure" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:197)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:128)
            at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:277)
            at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:372)
            at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:337)
            at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.JaxbRepresentation.getContext(JaxbRepresentation.java:97)
            at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.internal.Marshaller$1.initialValue(Marshaller.java:68)
            at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.internal.Marshaller$1.initialValue(Marshaller.java:64)
            at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:141)
            at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:131)
            at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.internal.Marshaller.getMarshaller(Marshaller.java:163)
            at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.internal.Marshaller.marshal(Marshaller.java:216)
            at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.JaxbRepresentation.write(JaxbRepresentation.java:538)
            at org.restlet.engine.io.BioUtils$1.run(BioUtils.java:305)
            at org.restlet.service.TaskService$1$1.run(TaskService.java:132)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
        Unable to locate marshaller.
```

Even if I try it with:

EstateResourceIF estateResource = service.wrap(EstateResourceIF.class);

```
    List<Preference<MediaType>> acceptedMediaTypes = new ArrayList<Preference<MediaType>>();
    acceptedMediaTypes.add(new Preference(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    service.getClientInfo().setAcceptedMediaTypes(acceptedMediaTypes);

    estateResource.postEstate(estateOne);
```

---

Some more facts for solution:

EstateDTO class:

```
    @XmlRootElement
    //JAX-RS supports an automatic mapping from JAXB annotated class to XML and JSON
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class EstateDTO implements Serializable{

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8545841080597549468L;

        @XmlElement(name="estateId")
        private String estateId;
        @XmlElement(name="owner")
        private String owner;
        @XmlElement(name="estateName")
        private String estateName;
        @XmlElement(name="street")
        private String street;
        @XmlElement(name="number")
        private int number;
        @XmlElement(name="extraAddressLine")
        private String extraAddressLine;
        @XmlElement(name="zip")
        private int zip;
        @XmlElement(name="country")
        private String country;

        private int space;
        private List<String> tenants = new ArrayList<String>();

        public EstateDTO() {

        }

        public EstateDTO(String estateName, String street, int number, int zip, String country, int space) {
            this.estateName = estateName;
            this.street = street;
            this.number = number;
            this.zip = zip;
            this.country = country;
            this.space = space;
        }
```

EDIT:

Server Sided Post

```
        @POST
        @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
        public Response postEstate(EstateDTO c) {
            //EstateDTO c = estate.getValue();
            System.out.println(c);
            String generatedId = generateID();
            c.setEstateId(generatedId);
            c.setOwner(sec.getUserPrincipal().getName());
            return postAndGetResponse(c);
        }
```

the system out on cosole says

```
 EstateDTO [estateId=null, owner=null, estateName=null, street=null, number=0, extraAddressLine=null, zip=0, country=null, space=0, tenants=[]]
```

postAndGetResponse Method:

```
        private Response postAndGetResponse(EstateDTO estate) {
            Response res;
            System.out.println(estate);
            if(EstateDAO.instance.getEstateDao().containsKey(estate.getEstateId())) {
                res = Response.serverError().status(409).build();
            } else {
                res = Response.created(UriBuilder.fromUri(uriInfo.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + estate.getEstateId()).build()).entity(estate).build();
                EstateDAO.instance.getEstateDao().put(estate.getEstateId(), estate);
            }
            return res;
        }
```

Dependencies:

```
                    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
                <version>${restlet.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
           <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>  
           <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.xstream</artifactId>  
           <version>${restlet.version}</version>  
        </dependency>

        <dependency>  
           <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>  
           <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.jackson</artifactId>  
           <version>${restlet.version}</version>  
        </dependency>

        <dependency>  
           <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>  
           <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.jaxb</artifactId>  
           <version>${restlet.version}</version>  
        </dependency>

        <dependency>  
           <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>  
           <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.json</artifactId>  
           <version>${restlet.version}</version>  
        </dependency>

        <dependency>  
           <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>  
           <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.xml</artifactId>  
           <version>${restlet.version}</version>  
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey JAXB -->
         <!--   <dependency>
               <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
               <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
               <version>1.12</version>
           </dependency>-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JAXB mappings appear to be correct, and since you have mapped your class with `@XmlRootElement` you do not need to wrap the object in a `JAXBElement`.  I also double checked and your XStream mappings appear to match your JAXB mappings (see below).  My current guess is the problem lies in your post method.  Could you add the post method from the service to your question?

**EstateDTO**

I have simplified your `EstateDTO` class by taking advantage of JAXB being configuration by exception.  This means you only need to add annotations where the behaviour differs from the default mapping.

package forum11410653;

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
//JAX-RS supports an automatic mapping from JAXB annotated class to XML and JSON
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class EstateDTO implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8545841080597549468L;

    private String estateId;
    private String owner;
    private String estateName;
    private String street;
    private int number;
    private String extraAddressLine;
    private int zip;
    private String country;

    private int space;
    private List<String> tenants = new ArrayList<String>();

    public EstateDTO() {
    }

    public EstateDTO(String estateName, String street, int number, int zip, String country, int space) {
        this.estateName = estateName;
        this.street = street;
        this.number = number;
        this.zip = zip;
        this.country = country;
        this.space = space;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

Below is some standalone JAXB code to ensure that everything works.

```
package forum11410653;

import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        EstateDTO estateDTO = new EstateDTO("Hotel", "StreetOne", 1, 111111,
                "England", 1);

        // setting up xstream
        XStream xstream = new XStream();
        xstream.processAnnotations(EstateDTO.class);
        xstream.autodetectAnnotations(true);

        xstream.setClassLoader(new EstateDTO().getClass().getClassLoader());
        xstream.alias("estateDTO", EstateDTO.class);
        xstream.alias("estateId", Integer.class);
        xstream.alias("estateName", String.class);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        xstream.toXML(estateDTO, writer);

        String xml = writer.toString();
        System.out.println(xml);

        // setting up JAXB
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(EstateDTO.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        EstateDTO unmarshalled = (EstateDTO) unmarshaller
                .unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(unmarshalled, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

As you can see `estateName`, `street`, and `country` are populated.

```
<estateDTO>
  <estateName>Hotel</estateName>
  <street>StreetOne</street>
  <number>1</number>
  <zip>111111</zip>
  <country>England</country>
  <space>1</space>
  <tenants/>
</estateDTO>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<estateDTO>
    <estateName>Hotel</estateName>
    <street>StreetOne</street>
    <number>1</number>
    <zip>111111</zip>
    <country>England</country>
    <space>1</space>
    <tenants></tenants>
</estateDTO>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added the server side. I tried your demo and it works. But still same problems. I cant deliver the object to my service, everythign is null, and still there is just the half coming back. Could there something wrong with the libraries? I already imported xstream of restlet and for json/jaxb jsersey-json.

Comment: Ok, just as I commented your post and posted my libraries I switched over to the restlet JAXB/Json Libraries. I edited the dependencies I have now on the project. Now its a new problem. Problem creating Marshaller

javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "com.bachelor.facade.object" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index I have to say my DTO Object is kept in another module. Should I add the libraries there as well?

Comment: @user1189762 - That problem occurs when you create a ‘JAXBContext‘ with a string representing the package name of the model.  Are you explicitly creating a `JAXBContext` or is it being done for you automatically.  Could you post the full stack trace.

Comment: I think its done automatically. I editet the full stack trace in my question. I solved this problem with a file called jaxb.index, where I declared EstateDTO. Now it works. Thanks for your help!